# urxvt: how to scroll terminal output / hide mouse pointer

Tags: rxvt

Two things that I miss in `urxvt` from `xterm` are:

1. How do you scroll up and down with the keyboard? In `xterm` I used Shift + Page Up (or Down), but that doesn't work.
2. A cool `xterm` feature is that when you type, the mouser pointer gets invisible. Anyway to get that in `urxvt`?

Comment: Not specifically while typing in a terminal, but you can hide your mouse pointer whenever you're not using the mouse, with `unclutter` (specific to Xorg, I think).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> (and <kbd>PageDown</kbd>)  works here, without any special settings...
2. Have a look at `man urxvt`:

   ```
   pointerBlank: boolean
      True: blank the pointer when a key is pressed or after a set number
      of seconds of inactivity. False: the pointer is always visible
      [default].

   [...]
   pointerBlankDelay: number
      Specifies number of seconds before blanking the pointer [default
      2]. Use a large number (e.g. 987654321) to effectively disable the
      timeout.
   ```

   This could be what you're looking for.  (The man page also explains where to set these Xresource directives.)

Comment: Second answer works great. Scrolling still doesn't work for me. Shift-PageDown gives me a dollar sign ($)! (I'll mark as correct. If it works for you, I got something wrong somewhere.)

Comment: Scrolling works with `URxvt.saveLines: 8192` in `.Xresources`.